# Adjusting Height and Centering

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a header/nav (from [www.mineplex.com](http://www.mineplex.com)) for my website, but I need some help. I'm trying, but it's not working. Your guys' help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code I have so far.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  background: #383838;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
    <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
    <!-- IGNORE THIS! THIS IS FOR LiveReload -->
  
    <div id="header">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
          <h1>WEBSITE</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of work done so far. Try to at least place your items in the header instead of placeholder text.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper Ok. Can you tell me how to add the darker div under the header to it?

Comment: You can learn a lot about a website's components via **inspect element**.. if you haven't tried that yet..

Comment: you should put more information here so we can understand where precisely are you getting stucked.

Comment: I answered how to add the dark bar below but as mentioned you should be far more specific in the problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add the darker bar in your header. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7z0wa696/)

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo">
            <h1>WEBSITE</h1>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="header-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: Helvetica;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}
#header {
background: #383838;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo {
color: white;
font-size: 15;
text-align: center;
}
.header-bottom {
width:100%;
height:25px;
background:#1E2224;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```